# How to computeAmountOut in Python?

Tags: python, swap, price, compute, httpapi

Assume i have the given information from raydium swap (retrieved it using simulateTransaction):

```
    {
'status': 1,
 'coin_decimals': 9,
 'pc_decimals': 9,
 'lp_decimals': 9,
 'pool_pc_amount': 689573985514,
 'pool_coin_amount': 41937737604483478,
 'pnl_pc_amount': 0, 
'pnl_coin_amount': 0,
 'pool_lp_supply': 130999637143208,
 'pool_open_time': 1702926900,
 'amm_id': '49VKXBqiNuEZXEPyDesZP1zniUeTPv9wcokpwShE9daH'}
```

I find it quite difficult understanding the maths in [raydium sdk](https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk/blob/master/src/liquidity/liquidity.ts#L2266). Can someone help in understanding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

```
def calculateAmountOut(amount, pool_info):
    status = pool_info['status']
    SWAP_decimals = pool_info['coin_decimals'] #swap coin
    SOL_decimals = pool_info['pc_decimals'] #SOL
    COIN_lp_decimals = pool_info['lp_decimals'] #swap coin
    pool_SOL_amount = pool_info['pool_pc_amount'] #sol
    pool_SWAP_amount = pool_info['pool_coin_amount'] #coin
    Coin_pool_lp_supply =  pool_info['pool_lp_supply'] #coin


    reserve_in = pool_SOL_amount
    reserve_out = pool_SWAP_amount

    current_price = reserve_out / reserve_in
    # print(f"Current Price in SOL: {current_price:.12f}")

    amount_in = amount * 10 ** SOL_decimals
    Fees = (amount_in * LIQUIDITY_FEES_NUMERATOR)/LIQUIDITY_FEES_DENOMINATOR
    amount_in_with_fee = amount_in - Fees
    amountOutRaw = (reserve_out * amount_in_with_fee) / (reserve_in + amount_in_with_fee)
    # Slippage = 1 + slippage
    # minimumAmountOut = amountOutRaw / slippage
    return amountOutRaw / 10 ** SWAP_decimals



def calculateAmountIn(amount, pool_info):
    SWAP_decimals = pool_info['coin_decimals'] #swap coin
    SOL_decimals = pool_info['pc_decimals'] #SOL
    COIN_lp_decimals = pool_info['lp_decimals'] #swap coin
    pool_SOL_amount = pool_info['pool_pc_amount'] #sol
    pool_SWAP_amount = pool_info['pool_coin_amount'] #coin
    Coin_pool_lp_supply =  pool_info['pool_lp_supply'] #coin


    reserve_in = pool_SWAP_amount
    reserve_out = pool_SOL_amount

    current_price = reserve_out / reserve_in
    # print(f"Current Price in SOL: {current_price:.12f}")

    amount_in = amount * 10 ** SWAP_decimals
    Fees = (amount_in * LIQUIDITY_FEES_NUMERATOR)/LIQUIDITY_FEES_DENOMINATOR
    amount_in_with_fee = amount_in - Fees
    amountOutRaw = (reserve_out * amount_in_with_fee) / (reserve_in + amount_in_with_fee)
    # Slippage = 1 + slippage
    # minimumAmountOut = amountOutRaw / slippage
    return amountOutRaw / 10 ** SOL_decimals
```